# PasteButton is not displayed outside of the root View after a while after launching the app

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI `PasteButton` will not be displayed in any view other than the view at the root of the `NavigationStack` after about a day has passed since the app was launched.

`PasteButton` is visible whenever it's placed in the root view.
However, `PasteButton` is not displayed in the view transitioned by `navigationDestination` of `NavigationStack` or in the view displayed by `sheet`.

Here is the complete repro code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showChildView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                TextAndPasteButton()
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    showChildView = true
                }, label: {
                    Text("Go to child view")
                })
            }
            .navigationTitle("Root View")
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showChildView) {
                TextAndPasteButton()
                .navigationTitle("Child View")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TextAndPasteButton: View {
    @State var text: String = "(initial text)"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)

            PasteButton(payloadType: String.self) { texts in
                guard let text = texts.first else { return }
                self.text = text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshots:

- Root view where `PasteButton` is always visible: [RootView](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1Sjq6H82Bmj4UmZwKG4jhPp-Dontm9jg6)
- Child view where `PasteButton` is visible correctly: [ChildView](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1_uSYqsKT1t6S-3ZPRe0dU-rgQl6SjKSK)
- Child view where `PasteButton` is not displayed that I'm reporting here: [ChildViewRepro](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1BmbxQXHQWw17mu5MgKFYy1bk0YXhlZy8)

Reproduction conditions are not clear; I have confirmed that the problem can occur after a period of time, such as a day, but sometimes the problem occurs within a few hours, and sometimes it takes 2-3 days for the problem to occur.

I have confirmed the problem on iPhone 14 Pro and iPhone 15 with iOS 17.2.1.
Xcode version is 15.1.

Can anyone point out if I am doing something wrong?
(I reported this to Apple as an iOS bug, but it's ignored..)